# My moodle website corrupted suddenly

Tags: syntax-error, moodle

My moodle website corrupted suddenly with this error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_USE, expecting T_FUNCTION in /admin/tool/log/store/standard/classes/log/store.php on line 30
```

What can I do?
Thanks

Current PHP version: 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading the latest version of Moodle from http://download.moodle.org ? (Or updating via Git https://docs.moodle.org/en/Git_for_Administrators )

Whether this is a bug in the exact version of Moodle you are using or a file that has been changed on your server for some reason, an update to the latest version is likely to fix it.